# Why don't we gitignore ios/ and android/ in react-native

Tags: react-native, gitignore

In our react-native project we often use the following scripts when switching between drastically different branches to avoid complications.

```
"eject": "rm -rf ios/ && rm -rf android && react-native eject",
"fresh-start": "rm -rf ./node_modules && npm install && npm run eject"
```

However if the `react-native eject` command changes many generated files in ios/build/ and android, why don't we gitignore ios/ and android/? In many github issues and repositories I see people at best gitignore their build/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the `ios` and `android` folders will have the native code required to run your RN app. If those folders were ignored, you would have to regenerate the entire project and run react native link each time.

Additionally, you may have custom native code that you need to run, which would be stored in the native folders.

Comment: What is the proper way to save that native code when you eject?

Comment: Native code will be committed to git, hence why you can't ignore the entire native folder. For example, if you have a custom Android RN Module, you may put it at root/android/app/src/main/java/com/company/app/MyCustomModule.java

Comment: What about `ios/build` folder? Do we `.gitignore` it or commit it?

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to start a React-Native project.
`create-react-native-app`
and
`react-native init`

In the first case, you will be avoiding the ios/android folder structure and rely on Expo to serve up your project.  This also gives you the ability to `react-native eject` to a structure that is similar to `react-native init`

If you don't need native functionality, then you can avoid using `react-native eject`.
[You can read more about it here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/introducing-create-react-native-app.html)

If you need the ability to integrate Native modules (Obj-c, Swift, or Java) then you need those iOS / Android folders and you have to eject.  There is information related to the building of the apps in Xcode or Android Studio in the iOS / Android folders. For example, there could be modules in the iOS/Podfile that need to be tracked in order to properly build the iOS app.  Ejecting isn't something you should have to do continuously.

If you're not using Expo to distribute the JS side of your project, then you will need another service to do so. [Microsoft App Center has support for React Native](https://appcenter.ms/)